# edit form adds new insert in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, insert-update

I have 'c_id' instead of 'id' in post table

Here is my Controller

```
public function editContact( $id = null ) {

    if( !$id ) {
        throw new NotFoundException( __( 'Invalid Post' ) );
    }

    $contact = $this->Contact->findBycId( $id );
    if( !$contact ) {
        throw new NotFoundException( __( 'Invalid Post' ) );
    }


    if( $this->request->is( array( 'post', 'put' ) ) ) {
        $this->Contact->id = $id;
        //echo $this->Contact->cid;
        if( $this->Contact->save( $this->request->data ) ) {
            $this->Session->setFlash( __( 'Data Updated' ) );
            return $this->redirect( array( 'action' => 'index' ) );
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash( __( 'Unable To update Data!' ) );
    }

    if( !$this->request->data ) {
        $this->request->data = $contact;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error

> Database Error
>   Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Contact.id' in 'where clause'
>
> SQL Query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `learnin_cakePHP`.`contacts` AS `Contact` WHERE `Contact`.`id` = '19'

But when i change this line

```
$this->Contact->id = $id;
```

to

```
$this->Contact->cid = $c_id;
```

It inserts as new record.

In my edit form there is:

```
<input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method">
```

I found that VALUE must be PUT not POST

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your model has

```
public $primaryKey = 'c_id';
```

In the controller, use

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
    $this->Contact->id = $id;
    if( $this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No matter what the primary key is named, you still have to use `Model::$id` to set its value! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178744/cakephp-why-does-modelsave-cause-an-insert-instead-of-an-update/19183214#19183214

Answer (score 0):

Add [primaryKey](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#primarykey) to Contact.php:

```
public $primaryKey = 'c_id';
```

Comment: I added public $primaryKey = 'c_id'; in Contact.php model but still not working.