# CakePHP converts ID field to $this->id in model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

CakePHP 2.6.x

I used the bake CLI to create my models, which created fields named `ID`. Notice it's uppercase.

So in my models, I was expecting to reference that property like this: `$this->ID`, as the property names usually match the field names (in my experience). It's definitely working that way in the controllers. For example, I have lots of controller code that looks like this:

```
$this->SomeModel->findById( $model['SomeModel']['ID'] );
```

However this **didn't** work in the model. After a lot of head scratching and experimenting, I finally figured out that the model property is named `id` (notice the lower case).

```
//in SomeModel.php
var_dump( $this->ID ); //NULL
var_dump( $this->id ); 33
```

Is this the expected behavior? Do *all* model properties get converted to lower case? If so, why is the controller different? Did I defy a CakePHP convention somehow? Any explanation of what is going on here would be most welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178744/cakephp-why-does-modelsave-cause-an-insert-instead-of-an-update/19183214#19183214

Comment: Never ever use $this->ID, always $this->id. That's what the `$primaryKey = 'ID'` mapping is for after all.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$this->id` you're accessing the Model's `id` property, not the value of the field in the database.

From source;

```
<?php
/**
 * Value of the primary key ID of the record that this model is currently pointing to.
 * Automatically set after database insertions.
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
public $id = false;
```

As Mark's suggested in his comment, use `$this->primaryKey = 'ID'` in your model to achieve the desired result, you could then do something like this in 2.6:

```
<?php
$this->id = 33;     // Set the active record
$this->field('ID'); // Returns 33 (If you really want to use uppercase)
$this->id;          // Returns 33
$this->read();      // Returns all of record 33
```