# Error update database in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I can not update databae Home vs field is: home_id, title, content:
I Update data in Controller:

```
   $this->Home->home_id =1;
        $this->Home->set(array(
            'title'=>'sdfjksdf',
            'content'=>'lkjskldjfkljsdklj'
        ));
        $this->Home->save();
```

But it is insert the table home,not is update???
I try

```
    $this->Home->read(null, 1);
```

But it is error, because Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Home.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: $this->Home->id =1 Pls try this

Comment: Combine Bogdan Kuštans and Karthik Keyans answer, and you shuld be good. Maybe see also **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178744/cakephp-why-does-modelsave-cause-an-insert-instead-of-an-update/19183214#19183214**

Answer (score 2):

In the cake php just we use 'ID' for primary keys name.

```
    $this->Home->id =1;
    $this->Home->set(array(
        'title'=>'sdfjksdf',
        'content'=>'lkjskldjfkljsdklj'
    ));
    $this->Home->save();
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inform CakePHP about your primary key

```
class Home extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = 'home_id';
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just for extends Bogdan answer, the better way on name your ids and primary keys is using the word "id".